# VBA Excel not working after saving and reopening

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that I was trying to use to sort some content at work. The code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
 
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("H2").Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), _
        Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    End If
 
End Sub
```

It works great when I first put it in and add some dates to the A column in my .xlsx file, however, after I saved it as an .xlsm file and reopened it, the program no longer did anything. Whats going on and how can I get it to work again? My coworkers aren't savvy enough to reenter this every time and I really just want it to sort anytime someone enters the date. How can I get this program to work any time someone enters the data? I've tried it in Module and in Sheet1 and no beans

**EDIT**
Working again, No clue Why. Just reopened the program a few times and it worked. I had the program in a module in an xlsm file (The one not working originally @findwindow) and in Sheet1 (Just to cover all my bases).
As for what the code is supposed to do, its supposed to sort the date entered (Column A) while maintaining the row integrity to Column H (Which it does well when it works). For Example, if I enter 5/24/2022 Joe ID8 NK *BLANK* Signed by NK then the entire row of content will be sorted to the space where 5/24/2022 would go chronologically. This is done automatically so that my coworkers don't need to constantly push sort (Which I've also had issues getting to sort correctly).

Comment: "works great when I first put it in and add some dates to the A column in my .xlsx file" not possible? Edit: guessing you want `Range("A2:H2").Sort`

Comment: comment that `On Error Resume Next` out with a leading apostrophe and excel will be able to help you debug with error messages.

Comment: @Lucretius I did that, however, there were no debug issues with that apostrophe. It did start working however with and without the apostrophe

Comment: @findwindow It is possible because I watched it work and sort the dates. Not sure why that shouldnt be possible. I'm trying to keep the rows all bound and the code does that perfectly, when it works

Comment: I don't think you realize the difference between xlsx and xlsm.

Comment: The code must be placed in the worksheet's module (of each sheet you want it to work in). The new file has to be allowed to use VBA (i think this is the problem most likely; check your setups). In order to check if the code is called properly, write a `Stop` line right at its beginning, then do something that should trigger it and check if it's triggered (the worksheet's module should appear with the stop line highlighted). At last a question: are you sorting just the H2 cell?

Comment: This code belongs in the appropriate sheet module, e.g. `Sheet1`, of a `.xlsm` or a `.xlsb` file. Using simple words, explain what the code is supposed to do e.g. if someone changes a value in the column range `A2:ALastRow`, sort the range `A2:HLastRow` by column `H` ascending. Adding a screenshot of your data might help significantly. You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72324457/edit) at any time.